# How to hide the black screen while loading scene / load level in the background

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, splash-screen

When I start my app, I get a temporary 8 seconds black screen right after the splash screen, and after that my heavy scene is loaded.
To solve this and after reading other questions- I added an empty Scene0 in order to load the heavy scene in the background. But it didn't solve the problem- I tried 2 solutions:

**Solution 1:**

```
 public class Scene0 : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public string levelName;
 AsyncOperation async;

 void Start() {
     StartCoroutine("load");
 }

 IEnumerator load() {
         async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(heavyScene);
     async.allowSceneActivation = false;
     yield return async;
 }

 public void ActivateScene() {  //Button 
     async.allowSceneActivation = true;
 }
```

Result: 4 seconds black screen after the splash screen + 4 seconds black after clicking the button (scene was supposed to be loaded so not sure why black)

**Solution 2:**

Removed `void Start()` function. And changed the button function to-

```
public void ActivateScene() { 
    StartCoroutine("load");
    async.allowSceneActivation = true;
}
```

Result: No black screen after the splash screen (yay). But 8 seconds black screen after clicking the button

Comment: Check out Brackeys 'How to make a loading bar in unity" on Youtube. It could be an easy work around.

Comment: I tried loading bar (I use asset LoadingScreen pro). But even after the loading screen is completed to 100% there's 4 seconds black screen

Comment: Because Scene0 is black, add some pictures for it.

Comment: And the usage of allowSceneActivation is wrong, check the document https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AsyncOperation-allowSceneActivation.html

Comment: You could also load the scene additive and remove the first scene (with e.g. only a canvas with a splash image/animation) only if the second scene is completely loaded